# Finding out which module set processor affinity mask

Tags: c++, windows, affinity

I am running into an issue where my 32-bit command-line application, when started from Windows Command Prompt or other means, is set to only use the first 32 CPU cores on a 64-core system.  Looking at that process's CPU affinity mask in Task Manager, I can see that only the first 32 CPUs are checked, and the last 32 CPUs are unchecked.

I made sure my code doesn't call SetProcessAffinityMask, but how can I see if any of the third party modules call this function?  And would doing things like calling SetThreadPriority change the CPU affinity mask?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 32-bit applications only get access to 32 processors.  Even if you're not calling the affinity APIs yourself, it's likely these are being used behind the scenes at initialization.

Comment: I was able to use Task Manager to change the CPU affinity and use all 64 cores on my application.  Also, other 32-bit applications on that machine by default had affinity for each CPU checked.